# Remove projectName from URL with REST with Jersey2 + Tomcat 8

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to build a simple REST service in Java (JDK 1.8.0.121) with IntelliJ IDEA, Jersey v2.25.1, Maven and Tomcat v8.0.14.

I've written a simple class with a GET method in the package com.example

```
package com.example.rest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

I've also created a main class that extends Application:

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public MyApp(){
        System.out.println("Server Up");
    }
}
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I run the application in my local Tomcat all works and the REST answers succesfully at http://localhost:8080/api/hello.

When I place the myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOP.war on my VPS, if I visit:
http://vps_public_address:8080/api/hello I get a 404 error

but if I visit:
http://vps_public_address:8080/**myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOP**/api/hello it works.

Why I have to write "myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOP" in the REST URL?

Is is possibile to avoid putting the war name in the request URL?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just rename your war file to ROOT.war and it will work.

Another possibility is to use the maven-tomcat-plugin for the deployment and set the context path in the plugin configuration:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
    ...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        ...
        </plugins>
    ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I prefer to use the plugin! 
I've tried to add it to my pom.xml (https://pastebin.com/ZT70915w) but it says that "Plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT' not found.". 
Have I to add a new repository?